# Very fast hash function for hashing 8-16 byte strings

Tags: php, string, hash, permissions, access-control

I need a very fast string hashing function, that fits well with web application written in PHP.

The problem I am trying to overcome is assigning IDs to permissions in an access control system. I am thinking about using hashed strings to represent IDs of permissions. This way I will be able to check permissions the way like this:

```
if ($Auth->isAllowed($user, "blog.comment")) {
    // Do some operation
}
...

if ($Auth->isAllowed($user, "profile.avatar.change")) {
    // Do some other operation
}
```

The DB table will map permission hashes to user's roles. To check that the user is allowed to do "profile.avatar.change" the corresponding string will be hashed and checked against DB table.

This is very handy and there will be no need to worry about maintaining unique permission IDs among different modules. But the hashing function should be very efficient.

Comment: Hashing is a one way street, so there is nothing you could check in a hash, other than its existence, for something like this.

Comment: the most common way is to follow linux approach. (using 0-7 to represent permissions). Assign ID's to permissions and do 2^(id number) to create an integer, then unroll it in the same way to figure out which permissions you have... Or just pass objects/tokens with a bunch of variables and check $user->can_change_stuff or $user->has_apples

Comment: @apokryfos, it is not a duplicate. These all questions are mine. This question is more specific about string hashing.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, that is exactly what I want to check - the existence of some particular permission in a database table.

Comment: The fastest way to hash a 8-16 byte string to a unique string is to not do anything at all to it. Just store it as is. It's short as it is.

Comment: @apokryfos, I have just checked the source code of YII. It seems like you are right!

Comment: @ezpresso check the answer, please. Otherwise half of your reputation points will disappear.

Answer (score 11):

The first though was *why don't he use a simple `md5` function?*.

**Trying to write hash by myself**

One of the [most frequently referred function](https://www.strchr.com/hash_functions) is a simple hash **Bernstein's function** also reffered to as `Times 33 with Addition`. It is used in `php` by zend [to make hashes for keys of associative array](http://php.net/manual/ru/internals2.variables.tables.php). In `php` it could be implemented as follows:

```
function djb2($s){
    $word = str_split($s);
    $length = count($word);

    $hashAddress = 5381;
    for ($counter = 0; $counter < $length; $counter++){
        $hashAddress = (($hashAddress << 5) + $hashAddress) + $word[$counter];
    }
    return $hashAddress;
}
echo djb2("stackoverflow");
```

The problem is that when it is implemented this way, it is rather slow. Tests shows that it is *~3 times slower*, than `md5`. So we have to find the fastest [internal implementation of a `hash` function](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.hash.php).

**Finding the best internal hash**

Just take all algos and measure time to hash a million of strings.

```
function testing($algo, $str) {
    $start = microtime(true);
    for($ax = 0; $ax < 1000000; $ax++){
        hash($algo, $str);
    }

    $end = microtime(true);
    return ($end - $start);
}


$algos = hash_algos();
$times = [];

foreach($algos as $algo){
    $times[$algo] = testing($algo, "stackoverflow");
}

// sort by time ASC
asort($times);

foreach($times as $algo => $time){
    echo "$algo -> " . round($time, 2)."sec\n";
}
```

My results was:

```
fnv1a32 -> 0.29sec
fnv132 -> 0.3sec
crc32b -> 0.3sec
adler32 -> 0.3sec
crc32 -> 0.31sec
joaat -> 0.31sec
fnv1a64 -> 0.31sec
fnv164 -> 0.31sec
md4 -> 0.46sec
md5 -> 0.54sec
...
md2 -> 6.32sec
```

The result slightly changes from execution to execution - the first 8 algos are shuffling due to their close speeds and its dependency on the server load.

**What should be chosen?**

You can take any of top-8 functions above: `$hash = hash('crc32', $string);`. Actually a widely used `md5` function is just 1.7 times slower than the leaders.

**Bonus**

[There are another functions like SuperFastHash](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/hash.html), that are not implemented in `php` code, but they are 4x faster than `crc32`.

Answer (score 2):

The processing time of a hashing function can be considered negligible in most cases. 
If you need a little hash (8 characters), you can simply use the crc32 function.

```
<?php
$hash = hash('crc32', 'WhatDoYouWant');
?>
```

You can also combine hash with uniqid to create random hash.

```
<?php
$hash = hash('crc32', uniqid());
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [xxHash](http://cyan4973.github.io/xxHash/). It's used by **PrestoDB** also. PHP implementation on [GitHub](https://github.com/Megasaxon/php-xxhash)